# JSON with android not working with android device

Tags: php, android, json

I have a problem with JSON login.

This is the PHP file:

```
<?php 
require "init.php";

$UserName =$_POST["User_UserName"];
$Password =md5($_POST["User_Password"]);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT User_UserName FROM User WHERE User_UserName = '$UserName' and User_Password='$Password'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];

if($data){
$response["success"] = 1;
         $response["message"] = "You have been sucessfully login";
 $response["UserName"] = $data;
         die(json_encode($response)); 
         }
                 else
                 { 
        $response["success"] = 0; 
         $response["message"] = "invalid username or password ";
         die(json_encode($response));
                } 

         mysql_close(); 
         ?>
```

Android:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue;

    String LoginURL = "..../login.php";
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {




                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LoginURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success "+jsonObject.getString("UserName"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
                                intent.putExtra("UserName",jsonObject.getString("UserName"));
                                startActivity(intent);
                                // startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),Welcome.class));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        parameters.put("User_UserName",etEmail.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("User_Password",etPassword.getText().toString());

                        return parameters;
                    }
                };

                requestQueue.add(request);




            }
        });
```

It is working with android emulator but not working with Genymotion emulator and not working with my android device.

Any solution?

This is the error:

```
dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzi
dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 547: Landroid   content pm  PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid  content pm  PackageInstaller;
dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error  warn.
dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid   view    SearchEvent;)
dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16064: Landroid   view    Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid    view    SearchEvent;)Z
dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16068: Landroid   view    Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid   view    ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid  view    ActionMode;
dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 317K, 11% free 3326K   3712K, paused 4ms, total 5ms
dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 626: Landroid   content res TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 648: Landroid   content res TypedArray;.getType (I)I
dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 589: Landroid   content res Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid   content res Resources$Theme;)Landroid   graphics    drawable    Drawable;
dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 591: Landroid   content res Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid    content res Resources$Theme;)Landroid   graphics    drawable    Drawable;
dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
libEGL: loaded  system  lib egl libEGL_genymotion.so
libEGL: loaded  system  lib egl libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
libEGL: loaded  system  lib egl libGLESv2_genymotion.so
EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 270K, 9% free 3568K    3908K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please post the stack trace if any.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect the code to do? What is it doing instead?

Comment: Does it say *I won't work* :D? Please post the error or explain the issue.

Comment: What's "..../login.php"? I think you can't use php in an androd device.

Comment: I use json to connect with php, mysql and Android

Comment: The code only register and login using php MySQL with Android